# How to use Web API with Areas and Same controller name in different area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-areas

The following Error i faced :

> Multiple types were found that match the controller
>   named 'test'. This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('JIB/api/{controller}/{action}') found multiple controllers defined
>   with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.
>   The request for 'test' has found the following matching controllers:
>   WebApplication2.Areas.JIB.Controllers.TestController
>   WebApplication2.Areas.JCB.Controllers.TestController
>   
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

```
 [Route("JIB/api/Test/test")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("JIBs");
        }
--------------
 [Route("JCB/api/Test/test")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("JCB");
        }
---------------
Global.asax


 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            JCBAreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            // GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }
```

---

JCBAreaReges
 context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "JCBApiAction",
               routeTemplate: "JCB/api/{controller}/{action}"
           );

```
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "JCBApi",
                routeTemplate: "JCB/api/{controller}"
            );

        //****************=======Default Route=========*******************
        context.MapRoute(
            "JCB_dashboard",
            "JCB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { Controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



        context.MapRoute(
            "JCB_default",
            "JCB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

---

JIBAreaReges
  context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "JIBApiAction",
               routeTemplate: "JIB/api/{controller}/{action}"
           );

```
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "JIBApi",
                routeTemplate: "JIB/api/{controller}"
            );

        //****************=======Default Route=========*******************
        context.MapRoute(
            "JIB_dashboard",
            "JIB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { Controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "JIB_default",
            "JIB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Why cant you you try to manage API Route config in WebAPIConfig.CS?

Comment: i tried but same thing  dear